# JWT Token Refresh Responsibility - Best practice

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token

I've implemented Jwt Bearer authentication on .NET Core API application and I would like to know which is the best place to renew the token before it expires.
Should the client (Angular) be responsible for renewing the ticket just before it expires or the server?
Moreover, are there pros/cons between the two choices?

Comment: Clients should be responsible for requesting to refresh their access tokens when they desire, this shouldn't fall onto the token issuer.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for that? Security? Standard pattern? what is the real benefit of having the client execute the request?

Comment: server doesn't need to track the token, otherwise you would keep track of every client which is against the principle of issuing tokens

Comment: To me it feels like it being the client's responsibility is firstly the standard way, and secondly the more robust way. If it were the server's responsibility, a continuous connection would be required between each client and the server. Because the connection's can't be fully reliable at all times, it's much more robust to have the client do the refreshes.

Comment: Also, regarding security- if an access token gets hijacked and you have server-side automatic token refresh that means the hijacker has permanent access to protected resources.

Comment: When using the Refresh Tokens, once the access token expires, the client requests a new access token by providing the refresh token. Once the refresh token expires, the client needs to authenticate with the authentication server once again. Reference: [ASP.NET Core 3.1 API - JWT Authentication with Refresh Tokens](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/25/aspnet-core-3-api-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens) and [Using Refresh Tokens in ASP.NET Core Authentication](https://code-maze.com/using-refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-authentication/).